# AVR atmega 32 C compiler

Tags: microcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux / Mac AVR Programming Suite?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/linux-mac-avr-programming-suite)

I have a Mac and I am confused about `c` programming in Mac and flashing it in AVR ATmega 32.

Does anyone know a toolkit for Mac OS?

Comment: Check [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/linux-mac-avr-programming-suite), it's about the same problem.

Comment: http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/developing-software-for-the-atmel-avr-with-avr-eclipse-avr-gcc-avrdude/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CrossPack](http://www.obdev.at/products/crosspack/download.html) with the Eclipse IDE. CrossPack includes avr-gcc and all the required files. CrossPack will also come with avrdude which you can use to program the microcontroller.

Be sure to download CrossPack-AVR-20100115.dmg and not the latest version - the latest version uses avr-libc 1.8 which can break some code.

To configure Eclipse, go into Help and select Install New Software. In the `work-with` field, paste: `http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/updatesite/`. Keep clicking Next - this should install the avr-eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Rowley CrossWorks for AVR is available for Mac OS X:

http://www.rowley.co.uk/avr/index.htm